# Do not install gradle sub-project as external dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-plugin

I have the following gradle multi-project structure.

```
root-project
   -A
     build.gradle
   -B
     build.gradle
 build.gradle
 settings.gradle
```

`A` has some plain java code and a couple of external dependencies. `B` has included `A` as `compile(':A')`. `B` also has a maven plugin applied as `apply plugin: 'maven'`.

Now my problem is whenever I do `./gradlew install`, `B` includes `A` as an external maven dependency. Whoever uses `B` is not able to compile because it does not find `A`. How can I skip applying maven plugin to `A` and include all of its code inside `B`?

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Publish the artifact to an external or internal repository
2. Depend on the project library directly as shown below.

-

```
// Project B
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":a"))
}
```

Ref:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I'm already doing this. But I don't want to publish A externally or internally.

Comment: Then option (2) is what you need then. Declare a dependency on `project a` in `project b`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But when I publish `B` it automatically publishes `A` with version `unknown`. I've mentioned that in the question as well. Sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

We've many alternatives if project `B` is producing a jar, but in my case, it's supposed to be a maven dependency used by third parties. I could not find a straight solution for it. So I ended up adding adding `A`'s sources into B. Something like this in B's build.gradle:

```
 sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir '../A/src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Only disadvantage with this is that I've to include `A`'s dependencies in `B` as well. I would be happy to accept if someone has a more elegant approach.